# Why does kerberos delegation only work in Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, kerberos, delegation

I've currently setup kerberos delegation on an IIS web server.

Users connect to a website on the webserver and can call for a SSRS report to be generated within the web application. The web application generates the report by calling the SSRS web service ReportExecution2005.asmx to generate the report and return the report as a pdf binary array which is then displayed on-screen.

The IIS website is running against an application pool which uses a service account. Both the IIS server and the service account are trusted for delegation.

When I view the site in IE and request a report then everything works great. When I place the same call via Chrome or FireFox the call to the SSRS server fails with a 401 despite a kerberos ticket being issued succesfully.

When I place the call to the SSRS service I've tried setting the call to use both the System.Net.CredentialCaceh.DefaultCredentials and System.Net.CredentialCaceh.DefaultNetworkCredentials

Can anyone explain to me why the kerberos delegation fails when the browser is not IE?

-- UPDATE

My initial statement that visiting the site in all browsers results in a Kerberos ticket being issue was false. Only when I visit the site using IE does it produce a ticket. Chrome / Firefox only resolve to NTLM.

-- UPDATE 2

I've now determined that both Firefox and Chrome do not use the Negotiate protocol by default. In order to allow kerberos based authentication with my site I had to explicitly state that it was a trusted site for both browsers using the about:config area.

If anyone else has the same problem please refer to http://blog.webonweboff.com/2010/12/integrated-windows-authentication-and.html

Comment: I think its an IIS problem. Not a browser problem. Searched a bit on the subject and a lot of other webservers seem to be able to use Kerberos.

Comment: Your "UPDATE 2" should have been made as an answer to your own question.